# Chartkick: Undefined method `line_chart'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am working on a **Rails 6** application and I am trying setup [Chartkick](https://chartkick.com/) for charts in my application.

**I installed Chartkick this way**:

1. For Rails 6 / Webpacker, run:

   ```
   yarn add chartkick chart.js
   ```
2. And in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`, add:

   ```
   require("chartkick")
   require("chart.js")
   ```

3 Install [Groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) to use the group_by_day method

```
gem 'groupdate'
```

And then run `bundle install`.

However, when I added this line to my Dashboard views:

```
<%= line_chart @products.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>
```

To show a graph for products using the `@products` variable:

```
class Admins::DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!

  # GET /dashboards
  # GET /dashboards.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `line_chart'
```

I'm wondering what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that I was missing the first requirement which is :

Adding this line to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem "chartkick"
```

And then running `bundle install`

My initial misconception was that I did not need this requirement since I am working with a **Rails 6** application.

I thought that this step only applies to **Rails 5** applications and below and not on **Rails 6** applications since I am running `yarn add chartkick chart.js`. But it turned out to be untrue. It is required for both **Rails 6** applications and **Rails 5** applications and below.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**